# characteristic equation - complex coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at a differential equation given by:

$$a_0\frac{d^ny}{dt^n}+a_1\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dt^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_{n-1}\frac{dy}{dt}+a_ny$$

Where the constants are allowed to be complex. When I look in different literature it all says that because the constants are real the complex roots in the characteristic equation will appear in complex conjugate pairs. So my question is whether the roots also will do this when the coefficients are allowed to be complex?

Comment: as in never or just not always ? Because I tried finding the roots for the equation : i*y''+y=0, and then I got that the roots were equal to +/-  1/sqrt(-i)

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not. If $p$ is a polynomial with real coefficients then $p(\overline{z})=\overline{p(z)}$. Thus if $p(z)=0$ then $p(\overline{z})=0$, since $\overline{0}=0$. With complex coefficients this does not hold. Indeed one can write down a polynomial with arbitrary complex roots: $p(z)=(z-z_1)\dots(z-z_n)$ has roots $z_1,\dots,z_n$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understand the logic behind the last part with why it doesn't hold for complex coefficients ? : )

Comment: @Linda In the real coefficient case, you can "factor out the conjugate". In the complex coefficient case, you can't. It's that simple.